# Keras shape error in applications Inception Resnet v2

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm using Keras 2.1.3 and I'm trying to fine tune a Inception Resnetv2 with Keras application.

So I load the pretrained model from keras.applications

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(299,299,3))
model = applications.inception_resnet_v2.InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', 
                                                        include_top=False,
                                                        input_tensor=input_tensor,
                                                        input_shape=(299, 299,3))
```

I create the bottleneck for my problem :

```
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(40, activation='softmax'))
```

And finally create a new model to concatenate the two parts :

```
new_model = Sequential()
for l in model.layers:
      new_model.add(l)
```

At this step, I got an error

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_7: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 192 but got shape (None, 35, 35, 64)

So I printed each layer shape and I have

> Layer n-1 : Input : (None, 35, 35, 64), Output : (None, 35, 35, 64)
>
> Layer n : Input : (None, 35, 35, 192), Output : (None, 35, 35, 48)

As you can see shapes dismatch and it seems weird that come from Keras.

**EDIT:**

My exact error is

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_7: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 192 but got shape (None, 35, 35, 64)

model.summary() (model is model from Keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2.InceptionResNetV2) give me for the **conv2d_7 layer**

> ---
>
> max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 35, 35, 192)  0           activation_5[0][0]
>
> ---
>
> activation_9 (Activation)       (None, 35, 35, 64)   0           batch_normalization_9[0][0]
>
> ---
>
> conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 35, 35, 48)   9216        max_pooling2d_2[0][0]
>
> ---
>
> conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 35, 35, 96)   55296       activation_9[0][0]
>
> ---

Comment: **new_model** is supposed to be the concatenation of **model** and **top_model**. So I first add all layers of **model** in **new_model**, but that doesn't work, error come from (~ layer 22th in application model)

Comment: Error : ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_7: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 192 but got shape (None, 35, 35, 64)

Comment: I edited with exact error and model.summary. I don't know what mean Input 0

Comment: with input shape (224, 224, 3) error moves on **layer conv2d_210: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 192 but got shape (None, 25, 25, 64)** and in [documentation](https://keras.io/applications/#inceptionresnetv2) default input is (299, 299, 3)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/27796/8560, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/27796/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.